# Vite - ouput directory not working for fonts

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, vite, laravel-livewire

I use Vite to build css and js in my Laravel + Livewire application. Currently I need to move assets to a separate folder. I was able to do this partially by changing vite.config.js like this:

```
export default ({ mode }) => {
  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [
      laravel({
        buildDirectory: 'myApp/build',
        input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js', 'resources/css/tracker-styles/fontawesome-all.min.css'],
        refresh: true,
      }),
    ],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap')
      }
    },
    build: {
        outDir: 'public/myApp/build'
    },
  });
}
```

When I launch `npm run build` it works almost well. The main css and js files load from the folder `public/myApp/build/assets/`.
The problem is Font Awesome. I import it via `fontawesome-all.min.css`, but when generating assets via `nmp run build` in `public/myApp/build/assets/fontawesome-all.min-[hash].css` the paths to the `woff` and `woff2` files are generated as `public/build/assets` completely skipping the `myApp` folder.

I've tried with various settings in vite.config.js, but without success.
How to solve this problem?